# Securing microservices behind a entrypoint with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Anyone know what the simples way to secure a microservice architecture that is behind a entrypoint?

The case is, we need a server that takes a TCP socket connection. The implementation to authenticate a user on this application is already implemented and it basically uses Spring Security with UserDetailsService and assigns the socket connection with the specific TCP connection.

But now we are considering going for a more microservices architecture, but we are having problems finding a good way to propagate the user to the different services.

E.g.:
User connects to TCP Socket server, authenticates.
User sends a request through the socket, the server propagates the call to another backing service (e.g. a Spring Data REST repository), but the call the client makes (e.g. a change request for a set of data) needs a specific user role. How can this role be checked?

So basically, the TCP server is issuing a service request on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the authentication procedure. If you already use a Single Sign On capable authentication such as CAS 2, you can add Spring Security on your micro services using the proxy feature of CAS.

If you micro services are hidden behind your front end application, that is if no user can directly contact them, you can simply pass the user id in the request between front end and micro service. As the micro service can only be hit from a trusted application, you can directly use the user id.

If you want to make use of advanced spring-security features (`@PreAuthorize`, `@PostFilter`, ...) in the micro services, you can use a custom `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationFilter` in the spring security configuration of the micro services, whatever the authentication procedure is. That filter would simply use the user id passed in the request to set the user authentication token.

All those solution allows not to cache the password in the front-end application, which is allways possible (in a session attribute) but looks as a bad security practice.

Anyway, you can use stateless security for the micro services part, since the frontend will always send a user id. According to [Spring Security Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http), it is as simple as adding an attribute to the http config : `< http create-session=stateless>` (this parameter exists since version 3.0)

If you use java configuration, you can do the same from a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void  configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: As I see it then, the socket server would call a backend service via REST. It would send the user ID. The backend service would then call a service that exposes users, which would return the user with that ID. But this would force the backend service to keep a session for that user wouldnt it? Meaning, when the client disconnects from the socket server, the session for that client would still be present in the session store of that service?

Comment: @LG87 : spring security can be easily configured for stateless RESTfull services. See my edit